# Dataflow from Azure to Google Cloud Platform using NiFi

Tags: azure, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, bigdata, apache-nifi

My goal is to move `json/xml` files from `Azure` to `Google Cloud Platform(GCP)` using `NiFi`. After my all R&D I figured out few `processors` that could be helpful. Lists are below:

1. GetFile
2. PutFile
3. putGCSObject- To put data in GCP
4. [Found this link as an alternative to get files from Azure since there is no in-built processor available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux)

The above link was complicated. So according to my objective am I going right ?? Do I need any extra processors ?? and also any important configuration I need to make while defining this flow??

Please help me out since I am a newbie and have just started with `NiFi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get your question right, your objective is to move files that are in Azure File Storage to Google Cloud Storage. Correct?

If that's the case, then you are almost in the correct path. As you have mentioned, Apache NiFi doesn't have processors for Azure Files right now so follow the Microsoft guide which you have quoted here and mount Azure Files to your Linux machine and create the flow like this: `ListFile -> FetchFile -> PutGCSObject`

GetFile or any Get* processors were of legacy nature and the new List/Fetch pattern is quite good as it helps you with state tracking, etc.,

BTW, you don't need `PutFile` since the objective of that processor is to write file(s) into local filesystem but we are here dealing with GCS as our sink.

Comment: Yes you got me right. So where do I need to add credentials of GCP ?? Do I need to enter it while defining PutGCSObject or some where else ?? And what is the difference between listfile and fetch file ?? Like getfile fetches the file itself.

Comment: You have to configure `GCPCredentialsControllerService` with your credentials and configure `PutGCSObject` processor to use this controller service. ListFile only brings the metadata of the file like the size, filename, type, etc., FetchFile is the one that actually brings the content of the file using the metadata provided by the ListFile processor. In a nutshell, Get* processors are not cluster friendly (intuitive distribution of data) while List*/Fetch* is good when clustered. Check this blog: https://pierrevillard.com/2017/02/23/listfetch-pattern-and-remote-process-group-in-apache-nifi/

Comment: That's cool. Thank you so much. I will go through this blog as well as ll start with the flow :)